# java collection framework problem

Tags: java, frameworks, collections

I am studying collection in java and stuck while understanding the following.It is taken from scjp by khalid mughal(review question 15.37)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
public class WhatIsThis {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<StringBuilder> list = new ArrayList<StringBuilder>();
    list.add(new StringBuilder("B"));
    list.add(new StringBuilder("A"));
    list.add(new StringBuilder("C"));
    Collections.sort(list, Collections.reverseOrder());
    System.out.println(list.subList(1,2));
  }
}
```

Select the one correct answer.

a. The program will compile and print the following when run: [B].
b. The program will compile and print the following when run: [B, A].
c. The program will compile, but throw an exception when run.
d. The program will not compile.

Following is the answer-

(c)
The class StringBuilder does not implement the Comparable interface. The sort()
method that takes a comparator does not place any such requirements on the ele-
ment type. The program compiles, but throws a  ClassCastException, as  String-
Builder objects cannot be compared in reverse natural ordering.

I can not understand the answer please.Can anyone help me out please ?

Answer (score 4):

Have you looked at the [documentation for `Collections.sort`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29)?

> Sorts the specified list into ascending order, according to the natural ordering of its elements. All elements in the list must implement the Comparable interface. Furthermore, all elements in the list must be mutually comparable (that is, e1.compareTo(e2) must not throw a ClassCastException for any elements e1 and e2 in the list).

and

> **Throws:**
>   ClassCastException - if the list contains elements that are not mutually comparable (for example, strings and integers).

Does that help you? Basically in order to sort the list, `sort` has to compare `StringBuilder` values with each other - and there's no natural comparison declared in `StringBuilder`.

Comment: thank you.I did not check doc (m a bit lazy and doc looks tough to me :) ).What I have understood is that StringBuilder overrides equals,hascode but not compareto and that is the problem.Regarding "Sorts the specified list into ascending order, according to the natural ordering of its elements"-except string and numbers,  how this ascending order will be implemented for other objects? I guess those class must override compareto method?

Answer (score 0):

The List is holding Objects whose type is StringBuilder.

When the sort is attempted the sort method needs to compare elements to decide the order, it does that by treating the elements as Comparable, it will try to cast them to type Comparable. As String Builder does not implement that interface the cast will fail and an Exception is thrown.

Comment: thank you,so its an exceptional class which overrides equals,hascode but not comapreto?

Comment: and so you can not sort a list that contains stringbuilder objects with Collections.sort method?